# Capturar grupos onde apareça uma palavra específica com Regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Tenho a seguinte situação:

```
text_1 = O cachorro correu com o gato
text_2 = O carro passou e o cachorro foi atrás
text_3 = Sempre que chego em casa meu cachorro pula em mim
text_4 = Ele foi correndo atrás do sonho
text_5 = O cachorro latiu para o carteiro
text_6 = Quando seu dono ordenou, corra cachorro
```

Quero pegar grupos com `"cachorro, pul\w+, corre\w+ e foi"`, mas que em todos os grupos a palavra cachorro esteja presente.

Tentei:

```
re.search((?:\s(cachorro|corre\w+|foi|pul\w+)){2,},text_n)
```

O que dá match em:

```
text_1 = cachorro correu
text_2 = cachorro foi
text_3 = cachorro pula 
text_4 = foi correndo
text_5 = None
text_6 = corra cachorro
```

O meu problema é com o match do **text_4**, esse resultado não me serve.
O que eu quero é saber se existe uma forma de dar match em grupos utilizando Regular Expressions onde uma determinada palavra, no caso **cachorro**, apareça pelo menos uma vez.
Outras variações da palavra `correr` e `pular` podem vir a ocorrer junto com cachorro.

Obg a todos.

Comment: Está meio confuso sobre qual é sua real necessidade. A expressão regular deve retornar qualquer ocorrência de `cachorro` seguida de outra palavra ou apenas as ocorrências com `corre`, `foi` e `pul*`? Pois no texto você diz uma coisa e no código parece fazer outra.

Comment: O exemplo é só uma ilustração, eu quero pegar grupos, não importando a ordem, onde a palavra cachorro esteja presente. Já tentei `re.search('(?:cachorro|(?:\s(corre\w+|foi|pul\w+)){2})', text)` o que daria match em {O `cachorro foi pular` a cerca} e tb me seria útil, mas pegaria ainda em outro texto {Ele `foi correndo` atrás do sonho} e não me serviria.

Comment: Mas isso não respondeu minha pergunta: deve-se buscar APENAS pelos verbos correr, ir e pular ou pode existir a ocorrência de outros que não foram listados? Por exemplo, "O cachorro latiu para o carteiro" deve ser um resultado?

Comment: Desculpe, tentei editar e passou o tempo, mas sim, grupos com as palavras  `cachorro, pul\w+, corre\w+, foi` não importando a ordem ou quantidade, mas em que a palavra cachorro esteja presente.

Answer (score 1):

**Resposta**

Se o que você quer é identificar as palavras que são precedidas por "cachorro " pode ser usado um *positive lookbehind*.

```
((?<=cachorro )corre\w+|(?<=cachorro )foi|(?<=cachorro )pul\w+)
```

**Você pode ver o funcionamento dessa regex** [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/jtacFC/2).

**Explicação:**

```
((?<=cachorro )[...]
```

A regex acima identifica a palavra "cachorro " (com espaço no fim), através de um *positive lookbehind*: isso quer dizer que identifica o uso dessa cadeia de caracteres e começa o *match*

```
[...]corre\w+[...]
```

Após isso captura a palavra a seguir se foi algo com prefixo corre, pul ou igual a foi. Acima está o exemplo com corre.
Com isso você pode acrescentar a palavra "cachorro " antes de cada match resultando no que você queria.

**O que você fez de errado**
Ao envolver o grupo de captura com OU (`|`)que nem você fez, acaba capturando todas as ocorrências das palavras `cachorro, corre\w*, foi e pul\w*` não importando as palavras que os precedem.

**Adendo**

Como citado nos comentários, caso queira usar algum outro antecessor que não seja cachorro, poderá usar OU, copiando a expressão anterior e mudando o antecessor e as ocorrências que quer capturar após ele.
Exemplo:

```
((?<=cachorro )corre\w+|(?<=cachorro )foi|(?<=cachorro )pul\w+)|((?<=gato )corre\w+|(?<=gato)foi|(?<=gato)dorm\w+)
```

[Aqui](https://regex101.com/r/jtacFC/4) **está um exemplo da regex acima em funcionamento**

Comment: Ola Paz, desde já muito obrigado pela disponibilidade. Nesse caso em especifico essa regex me atende, o problema é que os meus textos são um pouco mais complexos, existirão algumas exceções após a palavra cachorro. No caso o que eu quero mesmo é saber como fazer combinações utilizando as palavras citadas e que a palavra cachorro esteja dentro das combinações. Não quero combinações da palavra `cachorro` com qualquer outra que não seja `Pul\w+`, `corre\w+` ou `foi`. O look behind é muito util, mas limitado,pq se eu quiser colocar `gato` vou ter que fazer outro.

Comment: @Mueladavc editado